# Nrf24L01 with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

When I wanted to test my Nrf24L01 I wanted to be sure of it working fine, so I used this code for an Arduino Uno:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include "printf.h"
#define RF_CS 9
#define RF_CSN 7
RF24 radio(RF_CS, RF_CSN);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  printf_begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.printDetails();
}
void loop() {
  radio.printDetails();
  delay(5000);

}
```

The thing is when I opened my Serial, I got this each 5 second:

```
STATUS       = 0xff RX_DR=1 TX_DS=1 MAX_RT=1 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xff 0xff 0x00 0x00
TX_ADDR      = 0x0000000000
RX_PW_P0-6   = 0xff 0x00 0x00 0xff 0xff 0x00
EN_AA        = 0xff
EN_RXADDR    = 0xff
RF_CH        = 0xff
RF_SETUP     = 0xff
CONFIG       = 0xff
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0xff 0x00
Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = 16 bits
PA Power     = PA_MAX
```

Which apparently means that there must be something wrong with the connection, as far as I know .

noting that i have this Nrf24L01 with 10 pins, so i tried to attach it just like the following picture shows :

[image]

So I tried to plug it in with the Arduino just like this:
[image]

What was the mistake?

Comment: Voting to close as unanswerable, as the poster has admitted that the circuit does not match what is depicted but has failed to provide any information on what circuit they actually do have.  Questions abandoned in a form where they can neither be answered nor inform any similar problems merely clutter the site without being of use to anyone.

Comment: What is it that you are asking? I can't see a clear question.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem lies in your Arduino sketch, specifically in this line:

```
#define RF_CSN 7
```

Now, you have set RF_CSN pin to pin#7 while actually, its connected to pin#9

To get this to working you, try changing above lines of code to:

```
#define RF_CSN 10
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, true, that but I   just discovered that the pins aren't even like the http://i.stack.imgur.com/5epm9.jpg image shows, but indeed it's a whole different setup, so i managed to solve my problem, thnx for your help

Comment: @Medmalik - You should post your answer